# CallBack after object instanciation, which contains asynchronous function

Tags: android, api, class, asynchronous, kotlin

I got a Product class, which is constructed with a code. This code is made to call the open food facts API to instanciate all the class variables. The fact is the API call is an asynchronous function. So in my main Thread, when i try to access my object parameters, it's empty. Since i cannot interrupt the main Thread, **how am i suppose to make a callback on my object instanciation ?**

Here is the code

**Product.kt**

```
class Product(code: Long) {

    val client = OkHttpClient()

    var name: String? = null
    var imageUrl: String? = null
    var packerCode: Int? = null
    var packerCity: String? = null
    var lat: Int? = null
    var long: Int? = null

    init {
        run("https://fr.openfoodfacts.org/api/v0/produit/$code.json")
    }

    private fun run(url: String) {
        val request = Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .build()

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call?, e: IOException) {}
            override fun onResponse(call: Call?, response: Response){
                val jsonData = response.body()?.string()
                val Jobject = JSONObject(jsonData)

                name = Jobject.getJSONObject("product").getString("product_name")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

**GameActivity.kt**

```
class GameActivity : AppCompatActivity(){
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_game)

   val textView: TextView = findViewById(R.id.productName) as TextView
   val product = Product(3564700014677)
   // Product.name empty
   textView.text = product.name
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all we assume you don't want to use MVVM or so architecture. But I really recommend you to read about android architecture components like ViewModel, LiveData stuffs to understand how data flow should be done in android applications.

Coming to basics(Not very clean way), We have to create a interface and pass the reference to Product class and on success you have use the reference to call the activity to update the textview.

Step 1: create interface

```
interface ProductListener
{
    fun onSuccess()
}
```

Step 2: Implement ProductListener in your activity

```
class GameActivity : AppCompatActivity(),ProductListener {

 ...
 ...
 ...

 override fun onSuccess() {

    }
}
```

Step 3: Pass the listener/activity reference to the Product class

```
val product = Product(3564700014677, this) //inside your activity
```

---

```
class Product(code: Long, var listener: ProductListener) {

...
...
private fun run(url: String) {
        val request = Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .build()

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call?, e: IOException) {}
            override fun onResponse(call: Call?, response: Response){
                val jsonData = response.body()?.string()
                val Jobject = JSONObject(jsonData)

                name = Jobject.getJSONObject("product").getString("product_name")

                // invoke listener here to let activity know the response

                 listener.onSuccess()
            }
        })
    }

}
```

Step 4: Update the textview inside the onSuccess() implementation of activity

```
class GameActivity : AppCompatActivity(),ProductListener {

     ...
     ...
     ...

     override fun onSuccess() {
            textView.text = product.name
        }
    }
```